# Intune Wrapping Is required for apk?

Tags: android, azure, intune

I have few questions regarding microsoft intune wrapping.

My APP is going to be used privately.

**Questions**

1. Is it compulsory to wrap app with microsoft intune wrapping tool?
2. What is difference between wrapped V/S not wrapped?
3. I am wrapping app with **Invoke-AppWrappingTool** but it gives an error

> **Problem:** The output app was not signed because it targets API 30 or higher. The App Wrapping Tool only supports signing with Android Signature Scheme V1. Per Android 11 requirements, an application signed with Android Signature Scheme V1 and targetting API 30 or higher cannot be installed on devices running API 30 or higher.

> **Solution:** 1. tried apksigner suggested for such issue, apk was generated 2. Wrapped it with intune wrapping tool again.. it gives same error.

Anyone please help for these 3 points?

Comment: This [link](https://www.techtarget.com/searchmobilecomputing/tip/How-the-Intune-App-Wrapping-Tool-works-for-Android) will provide you with information about wrapping and why we need to use it.

Comment: Yes. I used that link only. but as stated above, I am getting Problem while wrapping it. which I mentioned as PROBLEM and SOLUTION applied. but still error is exists